# Как при изменении значения менять значения другой таблицы в представлении?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть БД с тремя таблицами:

- Таблица 3. PK ClientID, FirstName, LastName
- Таблица 2. PK InvestID, FirstName, LastName
- Таблица 1. FK InvestID, FK ClientID

Есть форма с listbox, в которой отображаются InvestID

```
lstAssignmentCases.DataSource = Датасет;
lstAssignmentCases.DisplayMember = "Таблица1.CaseID";
lstAssignmentCases.ValueMember = "Таблица1.CaseID";
```

При клике на строку в окне listbox нужно, чтобы в соседних lables или textboxes отображались FirstName, LastName из первой таблицы и FirstName LastName из второй таблицы, причем при щелчке на другой InvestID (строку в listbox) они так же менялись.

Не могу разобраться, как это делается в C#.

Comment: winforms? :-( боюсь, что вручную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повесить обработчик на lstAssignmentCases SelectedValueChanged. Не понятно что Вы используете в качестве ДатаСет, если EntityFramework, то с помощью Linq это будет приблизительно так:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ВашСонтекстБазы db= new ВашСонтекстБазы();
    int item = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;
    var tbl1 = from t1 in db.Table1
               where t1.ПолеСвязи == item
               select t1;
    тут заполнение лейбла и текстбокса значениями из tbl1
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! У меня датасет MS Access, в качестве дата адаптера OleDB. Я не очень понял насчет контекста базы... label1.DataSource = DataModule.DBname - вот так пробовал, нет результата

Comment: Контекст базы относился к случаю с EntityFramework. В случае OleDb Вы работаете с DataSet и BindingSource. В Вашем случае (по-быстрому, на вскидку) будет так:     private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int item = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;  
 var pos = Table1BindingSouce.Find("ПолеСвязи", item);
    var tbl1 = Table1BindingSource.Item[pos];
    тут заполнение лейбла и текстбокса значениями из tbl1
}

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень мне помогли тогда, хотя возможность ответить появилась только сейчас.